# How to play video from base64?

Tags: ios, swift, api, base64

I Have a JSON response with base64 file (video)

- How can I decode base64 to a video file?

```
let data = Data(base64Encoded: base64String!, options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters)
let nsurlItem = NSURL(dataRepresentation: data!, relativeTo: nil)
    do {
           let video = try NSData(contentsOf: nsurlItem as URL, options: .mappedIfSafe) as! NSURL
           let avAsset = AVAsset(url: video as URL)
           let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: avAsset)
           let player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
           let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
           playerLayer.frame = self.view.frame
           self.view.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
           player.play()
        } catch {
           print("\nerror", error)
           return
   }
```

3. What is next? How to play decoded string or data in the player. I received only error

Answer (score -2):

Try using `init(base64Encoded:options:)` initialiser of NSData. You can find more info [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdata/1417833-init).

Comment: How it help with playing the video?